# .htaccess stopping URL Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having issues with passing a parameter over the url and I think it is related to the .htaccess file.

This page:

```
site.com/apprenticeships/current_vacancies
```

has a link to this page:

```
site.com/apprenticeships/current_vacancies?id=1
```

on the page I have:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
```

and in the .htaccess file there is this line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^apprenticeships/([^/\.]+)/?$ content.php?page=$1
```

The page with the echo in does not echo out the id. Does anyone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `?something` is present in the second argument of `RewriteRule` (the part that defines what to rewrite to), then by default the query string is replaced. You want to combine both query strings, and you can do this with the `QSA` (query string append) flag.

```
RewriteRule ^apprenticeships/([^/\.]+)/?$ content.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```